# FineUploader - Error on multi-part upload to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I am using FineUploader to upload to S3.  I have everything working including deletes.  However, when I upload larger files that get broken into multi-part uploads, I get the following error in the console (debugging turned on):

```
Specific problem detected initiating multipart upload request for 0: 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.'.
```

Can someone point me in the right direction as what I should check for settings, or what additional info you might need?

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more information.  For example, what does the request look like?  What version of Fine Uploader are you using?  What sort of parameters are being associated with the file?

Comment: for the sake of others who find this issue. if your signingKey is 100% correct then your canonicalRequest sended by Fineuploader must differ from canonicalRequest on server that you create. For me it was a 'space' in host header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't included anything really specific to your setup, code, or the failing request, my best guess is that your server isn't returning a proper signature response for uploads made to the S3 REST API (which is used for larger files).  You'll need to review that procedure for generating a response to this type of signature request.

Here's the relevant section from [Fine Uploader's S3 documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/endpoint_handlers/amazon-s3.html):

> Fine Uploader S3 uses Amazon S3’s REST API to initiate, upload,
>   complete, and abort multipart uploads. The REST API handles
>   authentication by signing canonically formatted headers. This signing
>   is something you need to implement server-side. All your server needs
>   to do to authenticate and supported chunked uploads direct to Amazon
>   S3 is sign a string representing the headers of the request that Fine
>   Uploader sends to S3. This string is found in the payload of the
>   signature request:
>
> { "headers": /* string to sign */ }
>
> The presence of this property indicates to your sever that this is, in
>   fact, a request to sign a REST/multipart request and not a policy
>   document.
>
> This signature for the headers string differs slightly from the policy
>   document signature. You should NOT base64 encode the headers string
>   before signing it. All you must do, server-side, is generate an HMAC
>   SHA1 signature of the string using your AWS secret key and then base64
>   encode the result. Your server should respond with the following in
>   the body of an ‘application/json’ response:
>
> { "signature": /* signed headers string */ }

Comment: Is this true for a v4 signing or is this prior to when you implemented v4 signing?